# Array declaration: Dim arr() vs Dim arr

Tags: vba

Consider the two subroutines below. The first one works as expected, but the second one doesn't. Why?

```
Sub Test_1()
    Dim arr, s As String
    s = "Hi Hello"
    arr = Split(s) 'this line gives me an array
End Sub

Sub Test_2()
    Dim arr(), s As String
    s = "Hi Hello"
    arr = Split(s) 'this line raises the error 13: Type Mismatch
End Sub
```

Comment: Split returns a `String` array. `arr()` is an array of `Variant`s. In VBA, you must specify the type for every variable.

Comment: ^^^^^ `Dim arr() As String, s As String` works just fine.